# Possible to listen for event then return result from class?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, event-handling

I have an as3 class that I use for communicating with my Zend_AMF endpoint:

```
package test
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    import mx.rpc.AbstractOperation;
    import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
    import mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject;

    [Bindable]
    [RemoteClass(alias="Request")]

    public class Request
    {
        public var url:String = '';

                    //There are a lot more properties, but I have removed them for brevity

        public function Request(url:String){
            this.url = url;
        }

        public function send():void{

            //Create the remoting object
            var remotingObject:RemoteObject = new RemoteObject('test');
            remotingObject.endpoint = "http://site.com/endpoint.php";
            remotingObject.showBusyCursor = true;

            //Send it
            remotingObject.source = this.url;
            var op:AbstractOperation = remotingObject.getOperation(null);

            op.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, result);
            op.send(this);
        }

        private function result(event:ResultEvent){
            this.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

To use it I do the following:

```
var request:Request = new Request('someRemotingCommand');
request.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, catchEvent);
request.send();

public function catchEvent(event:ResultEvent):void{
    var result:Response = event.result as Response; //Get result as my response object
    trace(result.responseText);
}
```

All of this works fine, but it takes a lot of work to use it. I always expect a `Response` object when calling `send()` on my `request`.

Ideally I would like to be able to call `request.send()` and have it return a `Response` object directly and not having to deal with a listener:

```
var result:Response = request.send();
```

Is this possible? If so, how can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a time that elapses or code that needs to complete between an asynchronous event starting and responding.

The as code is not doing anything other that listening for the event to come back, it wouldn't make sense to hang while it is waiting.

If writing all the extra code is too much work for every event-response pair, create a factory class that will handle event creation and removal that would simplify it to one line, but all you're doing is hiding the event handlers, which you can't really avoid when it comes to asynchronous communication.

---

edit

You could create a class that bundles this into one abstract class, and different classes stemming from this class would handle different commands and responses differently.

> ```
> var request:Request = new Request('someRemotingCommand');
> request.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, catchEvent);
> request.send();
>
> public function catchEvent(event:ResultEvent):void{
>     var result:Response = event.result as Response; //Get result as my response object
>     trace(result.responseText);
> }
> ```

the utility of such a setup really depends on what you're trying to achieve though. With asynchronous calls, it'll always comes back to event handling.

Comment: I like the idea of the factory class. Would you be able to update your answer with a simple example?

Comment: Upon further investigation, I have a feeling that a factory might not be able to simplify the code down to 1 line due to not being able to return from an event listener function. Is this correct?

Comment: well you could create it in a way that you have the class constructor take two variables (`request` and `result`), the class would then update the result, as long as the response is not a simple object like string or number (because you can't do pointers in as3)

Comment: the problem is that you'll still need to listen for the change in the response object, so you'll end up with another listener anyhow. There's no point really of getting any information from the server if you're not handling it. I could see if you have a bunch of responses coming in, and you want one controller to handle it all, instead of having the dispatcher/request having to handle it, but that would just be a matter of assigning the listener to a different  class.